# Transfer files from Windows hard drive by Kali Live

Tags: windows, kali-linux, usb, boot

I have an old laptop with Windows installed on it, and there is a bunch of stuff that I need from it. My plan is to clear/format the Windows installation afterwards.

I've been able to boot with live Kali USB and access the Windows hard drive.
Let's assume the laptop has viruses from random downloading of software and plugging in of infected usb sticks.

- Is there a chance one of the viruses or malwares can run from the Windows hard drive on kali?

Let's assume the files are OKAY and not corrupted.

- is there any risk plugging in seconde USB to move my files to it using live kali?

Note: I can run the Windows from safe mode only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, viral files must be executed in order to do their work.

So there would have to be files on that HDD that contained viruses that could work on Linux, and you'd have to execute them in order for there to be any risk.

Plugging the drive into a Linux box should allow you to run a virus scanner on the files before you work on them, further protecting you.